# Excel formula to find word ending with

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I create a formula that only prints out the words ending with a dot. See below and image for examples.

```
7-5/8 TOWER ASSY. KIT -> ASSY.
90 DEG HYD.FITTING -> HYD.
90 DEG SPLIT FLANGE CDE. -> CDE.
```

Expected result:
[image: Formula that writes out only the words ending with a .]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it got kind of long but this seems to do the trick.  It will return the word prior to the first period in the cell and the period itself.

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))," ",CHAR(160),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))," ",""))))+1,FIND(".",A1)-FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))," ",CHAR(160),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))," ","")))))
```

Comment: I also add the formula with ";" =MID(A2;FIND(CHAR(160);SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2));" ";CHAR(160);LEN(LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2));" ";""))))+1;FIND(".";A2)-FIND(CHAR(160);SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2));" ";CHAR(160);LEN(LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2));" ";"")))))

Comment: The answer formula will error when there is no dot/semicolon or no space before the dot/semicolon. This modified version of the formula for dot `.` guards against these errors `=IFERROR(MID( A1, IFERROR(FIND( CHAR(160), SUBSTITUTE( LEFT( A1, FIND( ".", A1)), " ", CHAR(160), LEN( LEFT( A1, FIND( ".", A1))) - LEN( SUBSTITUTE( LEFT( A1, FIND( ".", A1)), " ", ""))) ),0) + 1, FIND( ".", A1) - IFERROR(FIND( CHAR(160), SUBSTITUTE( LEFT( A1, FIND( ".", A1)), " ", CHAR(160), LEN( LEFT( A1, FIND( ".",A1))) - LEN( SUBSTITUTE( LEFT( A1, FIND( ".", A1)), " ", "")))),0)),"")`

Comment: (1) Please don’t post answers as long and complicated as this one without explanation. (2) Egad! That contains `FIND(CHAR(160),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))," ",CHAR(160),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))," ",""))))` as a subexpression twice. That’s 136 characters! Use helper columns!

Answer (score 0):

For example your data is in cell A27.

```
=MID(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".", A27)), FIND("!",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".",A27))," ","!",LEN(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".",A27)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".",A27))," ","")))), (LEN(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".", A27))))-(FIND("!",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".",A27))," ","!",LEN(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".",A27)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CONCATENATE(A27),FIND(".",A27))," ","")))))+1)
```

Hope it is useful.

Comment: (1) Please don’t post answers as long and complicated as this one without explanation. (2) Your answer looks superficially like [Brian’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1414380/150988#1414390), which was posted four days earlier. Please explain how yours is better than his. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.